# Probability of product of $5$ digits being divisible by $5$ or $7$.

Tags: probability, contest-math

> Seven digit numbers are formed using digits $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ without repetition. The probability of selecting a number such that product of any $5$ consecutive digits is divisible by either $5$ or $7$ is $P$. Then $12P$ is equal to:

PS: I know this question has been asked and answered over  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2765084/probability-of-product-of-5-digits-being-divisible-by-5-or-7)  as well as on  [this](https://www.doubtnut.com/question-answer/seven-digit-numbers-are-formed-using-digits-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-without-repetition-the-probability-of--135900391)   site.Their answer is  $7$ but I've gotten $8$. I am unable to identify the error in my solution. Any corrections or full solutions would be appreciated

First I tried to define $P'$

$P'= 1 - P$

$P'$= probability of selecting a number such that atleast one of the consecutive $5$ digits aren't divisible by $5$ or $7$ or both.

We try to find $P'-$

*Counting of Favorable Cases:*

> Case $1$: Number has no $5$ or $7$ is $7!$

> Case $2$: Number has either $5$ or $7$. In this case the number $5$/$7$ can occupy positions $1,2,6$ and $7$ so that atleast one set of consecutive digits will not be divisible by $5$ or $7$. Hence $4\choose1$ $\times$ $7\choose6$ $\times$  $6!$ $\times$ $2$

> Case $3$:Number has both $5$ and $7$. In this case $5$ and $7$ occupy either positions $[1,2],[6,7]$ or $[1,7]$. So $3\choose1$ $\times$ $2!$ $\times$ $7\choose 5$ $\times$ $5!$

Favorable Cases = $7!$ $\times$ $(1 + 8 + 3)$

Total Cases =  $9 \choose 7$ $\times$ $7!$

$P'= \frac{1}{3}$

$\therefore P = \frac{2}{3}$, Hence $\boxed{12P = 8}$

Comment: Your calculation is hard to follow.  Why can't the $5,7$ occupy slots $7,8,9$?

Comment: wdym? its a seven digit number

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I thought you were just permuting the digits.  But in that case, why can't one of $5,7$ take the $7^{th}$ slot?

Comment: Actually, I stand by my first comment (though it was written with the wrong idea in mind).  Slots $8,9$ stand for the two digits which are not used.  You appear to be trying to count the bad strings (the ones for which you can find five digits in a row without either a $5$ or a $7$ so you need to consider the possibility that $5$ or $7$ (or both) aren't even in the seven digit number.

Comment: yeah so the 2nd case deals with a 7 digit number having either 5 or 7 and then either one of those selected numbers can occupy positions 1,2,6 or 7

Comment: @lulu both 5 and 7 are missing is covered by their case1.  Exactly one of those missing should be covered by their case2 (*though case2 has a typo, the "scary" digit could be in positions 1,2,6 or 7... while they accidentally wrote 1,2,5,6*).

Comment: But in that case, why isn't slot $7$ included?

Comment: @JMoravitz  Right, got it.  The omission of the $7^{th}$ position threw me for some reason.

Comment: i corrected it @lulu . sorry for the confusion

Comment: For what its worth, I believe your answer to be correct and the one in the linked problem to be incorrect.  The quoted answer reads "*Such a sequence exists iff at none of the positions 3,4,5 of the word we have one of 5 or 7*" but you correctly note that the sequence `5123476` every five consecutive digits has at least one of 5 or 7 present despite positions 3,4,5 containing the numbers `234` contrary to their claim.  I commend you for thinking for yourself on this.  Good work!

Comment: Now that I (finally) understand what you wrote, I don't see any problem with it.  I got the same result, working from scratch.

Comment: Alright got it. thanks

Comment: Now I'm wondering if the "*either __ or*" phrasing should have been an *exclusive or* rather than inclusive and whether that yields the linked suggested answer of 7 as believed by the previous question writer or not.  Either way, the claim in the linked answer does not hold.

Comment: The question will make sense only after a probability distribution is defined on the set of digits and only if repeated picks are independent.